# Retry sending a packet until it has been delivered

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm using an Arduino with an NRF24l01+ chip. Unfortunately, the "send" method of the Mirf library does not tell you if it has been successful or not.

Moreover, having a loop like this:

```
Mirf.send(data);

while(Mirf.isSending()){
 //Wait.
}
```

Just resumes even if the packet has not been delivered. Now, it looks like I do not have to re-invent the wheel, because reading the nrf24l01 [datasheet (page 27/78)](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/content/download/2726/34069/file/nRF24L01P_Product_Specification_1_0.pdf):

> Enhanced ShockBurst™ features automatic packet transaction handling
>   for the easy implementation of a  reliable bi-directional data link.
>   [snip] The automatic packet transaction handling works as follows:
>
> 1. You begin the transaction by transmitting a data packet from the PTX
>      to the PRX. Enhanced ShockBurst™ automatically sets the PTX in receive mode to wait for the ACK packet.
> 2. If the packet is received by the PRX, Enhanced ShockBurst™
>      automatically assembles and 
>            transmits an acknowledgment packet (ACK packet) to the PTX before returning to receive mode.
> 3. If the PTX does not receive the ACK packet immediately, Enhanced
>      ShockBurst™ automatically  retransmits the original data packet
>      after a programmable delay and sets the PTX in receive  mode to wait
>      for the ACK packet.

To enable this feature (datasheet pg 57):
[image]

It looks like I need to write something like 00011111 to register 0x01 on the chip. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Your NRF24l01+ chip is connected to the Arduino via SPI, correct?  The `W_REGISTER` command (write to register command) is described on page 51 of the datasheet.  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @angelatlarge Yes, thanks for that. The question is though, how do I send that command with my parameters through the Arduino SPI to write it to the chip? I'll take a look at some more tutorials.

Comment: The place to look is Mirf library source. At its most basic, you can use `MirfHardwareSpiDriver::transfer()`, but it looks like you may need to do stuff around that. See `Mirf.cpp` source [here](https://github.com/aaronds/arduino-nrf24l01/blob/master/Mirf/Mirf.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Mirf::writeRegister()` function.